# Как вставить [ ] по краям слов в текст

Tags: python, csv

Ребят, помогите пожалуйста. Короче есть текстовый файл, внутри файла около 25 000 слов с переводом слов, а именно с русского на английский, и есть скрипт, который эти слова загружает в программу, самого исходника нету. Дело в том, что скрипт, принимает слова в формате: [словодляперевода] - [перевод]. У меня в файле все слова написаны так: world - мир. Как через csv вставить [   ] по краям слов. Чтобы выглядело так: [world] - [мир]. Пример цикла пожалуйста если можно. Примечание: нельзя использовать регулярки.

Comment: у вас бывают слова, которые переводяться двумя или более словами?

Comment: Да, у каждого слова по 10 значений

Comment: я имею ввиду такой вариант: "word" - "словосочетание из двух или более слов" и все это в __одной__ строке исходного файла

Comment: Нет. Такого нет.

Comment: Т.е. таких слов как `"maybe" --> "может быть"` у вас в словаре нет? ;)

Comment: Такое есть. Блин, простите не понял Вас.  Я думал вы имели ввиду word - a  have word. Да есть такие.

Comment: И как такие варианты должны обрамляться квадратными скобками?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112120/discussion-between-success-and-maxu).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
l = ['world - мир', 'x - y']
res = []

for i in l:
    a, b = i.split(' - ')
    res.append(f'[{a}] - [{b}]')

print(res)
```